# How to prevent trimming on bound values in Angular

Tags: angularjs, data-binding

Consider the following HTML fragment:

```
<div class="text-center">
    <h3>LAeq: <span class="monospace"><strong>{{ Laeq | paddednumber : 7 : 2 }}</strong></span> dB</h3>
</div>
```

Where **paddednumber** is a filter that adds leading spaces:

```
    myFilters.filter('paddednumber', function () {
    return function (value, width, decimals) {
        if (value === undefined) return;
        var result = value.toFixed(decimals);
        while (result.length < width) {
            result = ' ' + result;
        };
        return result;
    };
});
```

How do I prevent Angular from trimming the leading spaces the filter has added?
I found the **ng-trim** option for the **textarea** and **input** directives, but the **Laeq** in the sample above is bound to a $resource and needs to be filtered to get the formatting right. I could of course do the formatting in the controller and then use **ng-model** on a **textarea** to bind to the formatted value in the scope, but I was hoping for a simpler solution in my HTML code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Angular is not the one that it's trimming the leading spaces, it's your browser the one responsible for that. For instance, consider **[this example](http://jsfiddle.net/k5c7bh9z/1/)**:

```
<div>
    Hello <span>               
                                Han</span>
</div>
```

This is pure HTML (no Angular), as you can see when the browser renders this markup, the browser ignores all the white spaces, carriage returns and tabs that appear until the next tag or blog of text. This is the standard behaviour of all browsers.

For instance if you do a right click on this same page and you select the option "view page source", you will see that there're lots of spaces, tabs and carriage returns that are being ignored. You may find something like this:

```
                        <a href="/review" title="Review queues - help improve the site">
                            review
                        </a>
```

Do you see all the characters that are being ignored by the browser?

That's why when you want to specifically say to the browser: "hey, this is a white space that I want you to render" you can use this symbol: `&nbsp;`, which is what you want to use for something like this.

But if you want your custom filter to render that symbol (`&nbsp;`) you need to either use its [unicode equivalent](http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/sgml/entities.html), in this case `\u00A0`.

That's why I've changed your filter, like this:

```
.filter('paddednumber', function () {
    return function (value, width, decimals) {
        if (value === undefined) return;
        var result = value.toFixed(decimals);
        var spacesToAdd = width-result.length;
        for(var i=0;i<spacesToAdd;i++)
            result = '\u00A0' + result;        
        return result;
    };
});
```

## [Working Example](http://jsfiddle.net/Lo8hntes/1/)

Comment: This works great. Thank you. But why? Was the trimmer in Angular designed to leave these spaces alone? Did you inspect the relevant Angular code to find this exception?

Comment: @Han I'm not in front of my computer right now. I will update my answer as soon as I can (1 hour approx) and I will give you a detailed explanation.

Comment: Ah yes of course. I should have known that but was too focused on Angular. Thank you for removing my blinkers.